# Jquery Button CSS - Padding and Margin

Tags: jquery, css, button, padding

Ok... This may be a stupid question, but I can't remove all paddings and margins from a simple Jquery button.

What am I doing wrong???

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/liviozanol/MLmtA/

```
body
{
    padding: 20px;
}
#btnClose {
        padding: 0px !important;
           margin: 0px !important;     
}
#IMAGE {
            padding: 0px !important;
           margin: 0px !important;
```

Comment: OK... I just want to make the button the same size as the image. Eg.: Removing space beetween the image and the button border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're simply targeting the wrong elements - the padding is on `<span class="ui-button-text">`  not its containing div. Use `#btnClose .ui-button-text` to override the current declaration

http://jsfiddle.net/MLmtA/2/

```
#btnClose .ui-button-text {
padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Common tip:
You must learn to use debugger. It simplify your work. For similar task you should discover HTML element at DOM by debuger (i.e [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/), ) and from a context you will see problem

At particular case:
jquery-ui had a own styles and you must set style for inner a tag span.